# How to execute a method for only one time when the application is downloaded from store

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-store

I am new to windows.I have one small issue i.e I want to download a folder for the first time when the application is launched.After the file  is download I want to move to the Main Page.

```
StorageFile localFile = await destinationFolder.CreateFileAsync(localFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(m_source, localFile);
```

I have used this code for download in mainpage.

Answer (score 0):

Create a fake splash screen. When the app starts, check if the file is downloaded (exists). If yes, go to the main page. If not, go to the fake splacscreen, download the file and when the download finishes, go to the main page.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your question. You said you want to download a folder then you want to go to the MainPage. But the code you are using is already on MainPage. That Means you don't know what you are doing.

I agree with Igor Kulman. What else you can do is just hide everything in the MainPage and when the downloading is complete, show what you want on your page. While downloading you can show progress bar that tells user that something is going on.

Comment: i want the download to be happened only for one time i.e when the application is downloaded for the first time from the store.

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: How to navigate to mainpage.xaml.cs from onlaunch()in appx.xaml.cs every time when app is open .